# DevExpress Legacy ASPxGridView: How to have column header CheckBox check all or clear all; also have individual row CheckBoxes affect header CheckBox?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, checkbox, devexpress, aspxgridview

Forgive the seemingly repeated question but after two hours and poring over several code samples, I've not seen one that actually works for me.

I have a client I am doing work for which has the classic UI need of wanting a grid with the first column being checkboxes...  with a checkbox header, which when clicked can select all (or clear all) of the other checkboxes in each data row. If an individual row's checkbox is checked, they want that status reflected in the header checkbox; i.e. the header checkbox is only checked if all other visible rows are also checked. I also want to be able to (of course) perform some action based on checked/selected rows on the server side.

I am constrained to using their currently-licensed version of the DevExpress controls which is 12.2.5, and I am of course using the ASPxGridView as this is a web application. As I've already stated, after looking at several code examples I cannot seem to make this work properly. I've pasted in a simplified version of the code I am working on, in the hopes I can get some guidance here. (NOTE: Please DO NOT suggest things such as "upgrade to the latest version", I don't have that option available to me here!) Thanks much in advance for your assistance.

Barry L. Camp

Code follows:

**ASPX Page**

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="TestPage.aspx.vb" Inherits="TestApp.TestPage" %>

<%@ Register assembly="DevExpress.Web.v12.2, Version=12.2.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" namespace="DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView" tagprefix="dx" %>
<%@ Register assembly="DevExpress.Web.v12.2, Version=12.2.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" namespace="DevExpress.Web.ASPxEditors" tagprefix="dx" %>

<!doctype html />

<html>
<head>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    function checkAllCheckBox_OnCheckedChanged(sender, e) {
      var checked = sender.GetChecked();
      // Loop to set all checkboxes to column header checkbox state...?
    }
  </script>

</head>

<body>
  <dx:ASPxGridView ID="SomeInformationGridView" runat="server" KeyFieldName="ID" ClientInstanceName="grid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SettingsPager-Mode="ShowPager" SettingsPager-PageSize="50" style="width: 95%;">
    <SettingsBehavior AllowGroup="false" AllowDragDrop="false" />

    <Columns>

      <dx:GridViewCommandColumn ShowSelectCheckbox="true" VisibleIndex="0" Width="32px" CellStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
        <HeaderTemplate>
          <dx:ASPxCheckBox ID="CheckAllCheckBox" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" clientinstancename="checkAllCheckBox" OnInit="CheckAllCheckBox_Init">
            <ClientSideEvents CheckedChanged="checkAllCheckBox_OnCheckedChanged" />
          </dx:ASPxCheckBox>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
      </dx:GridViewCommandColumn>

      <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="ID" VisibleIndex="1" Visible="false" ReadOnly="true" CellStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
      </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
      <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="SomeOtherData" VisibleIndex="2" Visible="true" ReadOnly="true" CellStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
      </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>

      <--! Other Columns Here -->

    </Columns>
  </dx:ASPxGridView>

</body>
</html>
```

**VB Code-Behind**

```
Imports System
Imports System.Web.UI
Imports DevExpress.Web.ASPxEditors
Imports DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView

Partial Public Class TestPage
    Inherits Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim gridView As ASPxGridView = CType(Me.FindControl("SomeInformationGridView"), ASPxGridView)
        gridView.DataSource = GetMyInformation()
        gridView.DataBind()
    End Sub

    Protected Sub CheckAllCheckBox_Init(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Dim checkBox As ASPxCheckBox = sender
        Dim grid As ASPxGridView = SomeInformationGridView ' CType(Me.FindControl("SomeInformationGridView"), ASPxGridView)
        checkBox.Checked = (grid.Selection.Count = grid.VisibleRowCount)
    End Sub

    Private Function GetMyInformation()
      ' Reads the data to be bound to the grid.
    End Function
End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am constrained to using their currently-licensed version of the DevExpress controls which is 12.2.5

Yes, if you are using such an older version, it is necessary to emulate this functionality using a bunch of code.

Check out the [OBSOLETE - ASPxGridView - How to implement SelectRows and SelectAllRowsOnPage CheckBox features](https://www.devexpress.com/kbid=K18253) instruction to find how to accomplish this.

Comment: Appreciate the response, but this was one of the articles I read prior to posting my question. It did not work for me; further, I only need one of the checkboxes not both, this complicated matters.

Comment: Then, implement the required one (for a single page or for all pages). There is a link to a working example in the end.

Comment: Finally got this to work but I had to modify the solution to account only for the "cbPage" variant. The customer only wanted that behavior, and understood the implications of having to select all rows, one page at a time. To have two checkboxes in the header was considered confusing, and I tend to agree. But, I have implemented this now and have marked this as the solution. Thanks much for your help.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding the following js and html call in the gridheader template:

```
       //javascript function 
     function CheckAll(chkBx, gvID)
    {
        var gv = document.getElementById(gvID);
        for (i = 1; i < gv.rows.length; i++) {
            if (gv.rows[i].style.display != 'none') {
                gv.rows[i].cells[0].getElementsByTagName("INPUT")[0].checked = chkBx.checked;
            }
        };
    };

   //add this to your grid header template
   <HeaderTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkAllAvail"  ToolTip="Select all" runat="server"   onclick="CheckAll(this, 'SomeInformationGridView');"    Visible="true" />
         </HeaderTemplate>
```

Comment: Thanks much...  will take a look when I get back to work in the morning.

Comment: Sorry, but this did not fully work out for me. I need to utilize the DevExpress controls and I still need to leverage the checkbox values of all rows on the server side of each. I appreciate your effort to answer though, and you should know that it was not me who downvoted your answer.